# Quero busca informação de uma tabela com EF

Tags: c#, angularjs, entity-framework

Tenho o seguinte código form:

```
@model Domain.Entities.Tabela1
@using WebUI.HtmlHelpers
@using WebUI.Extensions
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Tabela";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Master.cshtml";
}
<article ng-app="registrationModule">
    <section>
        <div>
            <div ng-controller="Tabela1FormController">
                <form class="form" name="tabela1Form" ng-submit="save(tabela1)" novalidate style="width: 700px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">

                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="name">Nome:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="tabela1.name" />
                        </div>
                    </div> 
//Aqui eu gostaria de busca a informação
<input type="text" name="name" ng-model="tabela2.medida" />
```

Meu Entities Tabela1:

```
[Table("Tabela1")]
    public class Tabela1
    {
        [Key]
        public int tabela1ID{ get; set; }

        //Strings
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo \"Nome\" é obrigatório")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage="O campo \"Unidade de Medida\" é obrigatório")]
        public string medida{ get; set; }


        //Collections
        public ICollection<Coleçao> campo { get; set; }


        public tabela1()
        {
            campo= new HashSet<Coleçao>();   
}
```

Entitie tabela2:

```
public class tabela2
    {
        public static tabela2 Default = new tabela2();

        [Key]
        public int tabela2ID { get; set; }
        public string Unit { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Digite um símbolo da unidade de medida")]
        public string Symbol { get; set; }

    }
```

ListView tabela1

```
 public class tabela1ListViewModel : PaginationViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<tabela1> tabela1{ get; set; }
    }
```

Meu controle:

```
  public ActionResult Newtabelar()
    {
        return View("tabelaForm");
    }

[Permission(Path = IndicatorPath.tabela, Permission = PermissionType.ReadWrite)]
public ActionResult EditItabela(int tabelaid, bool onlyRead = false)
{
    var tabela = tabela1Repository
        .tabela1
        .Include(x => x.tabela3)
            .Include(x => x.tabela4)
            .Include(x => x.tabela5)
            .Include(x => x.tabela6)
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.tabela1id == tabela1id);

    ViewBag.OnlyRead = onlyRead;

    return View("tabela1Form", tabela);
}
```

Bom a tabela1 um ele busca ok, porém a tabela2 quero jogar os campo que ela tem em um select no form ele não busca, minha view foi feita com angular, como devo proceder para resolver esse problema. obrigado desde já.

Comment: Como assim "não busca", pode explicar melhor? Dá erro? Qual código você está usando para obter os valores da tabela?

Comment: não consigo trazer as informação da tabela2 para o campo desejado.

Comment: A tabela1 tem relação com outras duas e a tabela2 não.

Comment: O que exatamente você quer acessar, que não esta conseguindo?

Comment: eu quero acessa o campo unit da tabela2, nao sei se pelo angulajs que eu pego as informação e colocar no <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="tabela2.medida" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Você poderá usar uma ViewModel:**

```
public class ViewModel1
{
   public Tabela1 tabela1 { get; set; }
   public Tabela2 tabela2 { get; set; }
}
```

**Action:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new ViewModel1();

    // Preencha as propriedades do objeto viewModel1

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Dai você poderá usar o model tabela2 na sua View.

Comment: Vou tentar la obrigado

Comment: infelizmente  não conseguir implementar o código

Comment: qual foi a dificuldade?

Comment: Preencha as propriedades do objeto viewModel1

Comment: As propriedades são tabela1 e tabela2, você deve instancia-las, preencher os objetos como desejar, e depois usar na sua view